# Self Organizing Map memory error with numpy.Zeros(x*y,x*y)? what should my X/Y represent?

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence, self-organizing-maps

I'm trying to experiment with [Stephan Marslands 2D Self-Organzing Map](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/smarsland/Code/9/som.py) (In conjunction with [Principal Components Analysis](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/smarsland/Code/10/pca.py))

```
import som as sm
#put it into som
def som_algorithm(inputs,nIterations,x=0,y=0):
    print "Running Self-Organizing Map!"
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        y = len(inputs[0])
        x = len(inputs)
    print "x axis is " + str(x) + " / y axis is " + str(y)
    som = sm.som(x,y,inputs)
    som.somtrain(inputs, nIterations)
    print som.somfwd(inputs)

som_algorithm(training, 100)
```

And based on my data set [after preprocessing](http://csgo.co.nz/06005586/lingspam.py), produces this error

```
Running Self-Organizing Map!
x axis is 600 / y axis is 173
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\source\bag_of_words.py", line 112, in <module>
som_algorithm(training, 100)
  File "\source\bag_of_words.py", line 87, in som_algorithm
som = sm.som(x,y,inputs)
  File "\som\__init__.py", line 44, in __init__
self.mapDist = zeros((self.x*self.y,self.x*self.y))
MemoryError
```

Currently my `Y` represents the amount of elements per array (array dimension contained within the larger dimension) and my `X` represents the larger dimension containing smaller array dimensions. What could be causing this memory error?

Comment: What is `training` in the code above and where is it instantiated in Python?

Comment: The training code is the `array variable` within [this](http://csgo.co.nz/06005586/lingspam.py), link has also been provided in the question under "_after preprocessing_". (it is too large to include in the question 600x173 dimensions (103,800 elements)) Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is trying to create an array of zeros with shape x*y by x*y.  Thats 10774440000 elements.  Each value in the array is 8 bytes (double precision).  That's over 80 gigabytes.  You are simply running out of memory.